# CakePhp and jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm still really new to CakePhp, so if I leave anything out, let me know.  I am trying to create a form that post back to the controller using ajax.  Here is what I have:

Model:  EventExampleModel

```
class EventExampleModel extends AppModel {

}
```

View:  /app/View/EventExample/index.ctp

```
<?php

$data = $this->Js->get('#CommentSaveForm')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
$this->Js->get('#CommentSaveForm')->event(
    'submit',
    $this->Js->request(
        array('action' => 'save'),
        array(
            'update' => '#commentStatus',
            'data' => $data,
            'async' => true,
            'dataExpression'=>true,
            'method' => 'POST'
        )
    )
);
echo $this->Form->create('Commenter', array('action' => 'save', 'default' => false));
echo $this->Form->input('Commenter.comments_name');
echo $this->Form->input('Commenter.comments_text');
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();

?>

<div id="contactStatus">


</div>
```

Controller:  EventExampleController:

```
class EventExampleController extends Controller {
  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public function index() {
        $this->layout = 'homePage';
    }
    public function save() {

        if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->render('contact-ajax-response', 'ajax');
        }
    }
}
```

and my layout:

```
<?php
$cakeDescription = __d('cake_dev', 'Employee Database');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>
        <?php echo $cakeDescription ?>
    </title>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    echo $this->Html->css('styles');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.10.2.js'); // Include jQuery library
    echo $this->Html->script('myScripts');
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="homepage-container">
    <div id="content">
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also have the jquery library located in the app/webroot/js folder.

The problem is that when the page renders and I click the submit button, nothing happens.  I see no errors on the page or in the console and the page does not post back.  What am I missing?  I expect the page to post back to the server, asynchronously and my save function should get called (the break point never gets hit).

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1):

Your model name is wrong

The right convention is

```
EventExample extends AppModel
```

And file name
EventExample.php

Just a tip.

Open your firebug or equivalent in google chrome and check the network tab.
Check if something is triggered when you click the button please.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the response.  I changed the model as suggested.  But, when i click the button, still nothing happens.  I even opened up the developer tools and looked in the Network tab and there is nothing. Any suggestions on what I might be missing?